# How to take a screen capture of a hidden/partially hidden window with Python

Tags: python, screenshot

I'm trying to create a Python program that takes screen capture of a specific window that is hidden/partialy hidden by other windows. I've searched for code on the web but none of them seems to work with Windows 11 & Python 3.8+. What is the simplest way of doing this?

Like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture) if possile

Answer (score 0):

If a window is hidden it doesn't get rendered, so there is nothing to take a screenshot of.